# What does unactivated, activated and deactivated aryl chloride mean in cross-coupling reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology, organometallic-compounds

Hartwig et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo990408i)] used unactivated aryl chloride for Buchwald–Hartwig amination. What does *unactivated*, *activated* and *deactivated* aryl chloride mean in a cross-coupling reaction?

#### Reference

1. Hartwig, J. F.; Kawatsura, M.; Hauck, S. I.; Shaughnessy, K. H.; Alcazar-Roman, L. M. Room-Temperature Palladium-Catalyzed Amination of Aryl Bromides and Chlorides and Extended Scope of Aromatic C−N Bond Formation with a Commercial Ligand. *J. Org. Chem.* **1999**, 64 (15), 5575–5580. DOI: [10.1021/jo990408i](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo990408i).